# creating files in multiple directories

Tags: bash, unix

Is it possible to create files in multiple directirories at once / in one command? 
Im doing something like this

```
Add 

    -add1
         - file 1
         - file 2
    -add2
         - file 1
         - file 2
```

I'm creating directories with

```
mkdir -p Add/add{1,2}
```

but can't figure out how to create files in each subdirectory without manualy swaping to directory and creating a file there.

Comment: What do you want to store in those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same technique:

```
touch Add/add{1,2}/file{1,2}
```

With `set -x` you'll see that it gets expanded to:

```
touch Add/add1/file1 Add/add1/file2 Add/add2/file1 Add/add2/file2
```

Comment: A trick I like to do when using filename expansion like this is first echo it `echo  Add/add{1,2}/file{1,2}`, verify the files look correct and then run the actual command using `^echo^touch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loops if your Unix shell is Bash:

```
$ for dir in add1 add2; do mkdir -vp $dir; for file in file1 file2; do echo creating $dir/$file; touch $dir/$file; done; done
```

This produces this output:

```
mkdir: created directory ‘add1’
creating add1/file1
creating add1/file2
mkdir: created directory ‘add2’
creating add2/file1
creating add2/file2
```